# Background app best practices

Tags: java, android, mobile

Is Service and Notification the correct way to implement a background app with the following behavior?

1- User open the app, make some configurations and touch in a "run" button;
2- The main activity must be closed and a background service will be started;
3- A fixed notification will be displayed with some buttons ("stop" to finish the service and "Reconfigure");

thank you

Comment: What kind of work service will do?

Comment: Network stats for example. It should behave like a player app

Comment: Service - it is activity without UI, you have right vision of how it works, but you said about "stop" button, if you want to show it, you should show Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did an app that at short intervals (1 to 10 sec) acquires constantly data from a remote TCP server, even on the background also with the screen off.

In the Main Activity onStop I acquire a Partial WakeLock and I start the Service with STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION intent, the Service calls startForeground and shows the Notification.

On Activity onResume the WakeLock is released, the Service stops with STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION intent and the Service itself calls stopForeground & stopSelf.

I don't have buttons in the notification, if user touches the notification the Activity is shown.

It works very well I tested it with hours of continuous operation.

Comment: Yeah, in my tests the system never killed the application.

Comment: Thanks Tonteria24, but when I closed the app in task manager my notification is closing too. Is there any way to keep the notification and the service running even the app closed by task manager?

To be honest I would like to close the main screen with the action of the user and just keep the notification and the service running.

Comment: Android is not designed to run servers permanently, you should give the possibility to stop the server to avoid draining the battery. I have no solution for what you say.

Comment: Thank you very much